# Extract A Specific Part From Text - Python

Tags: python, text, split, detect

i want to extract a part of text that begins for example with

"Hello" and ends with "goodbye"

Example:

Extract the sentence `Hello i'm Gabi, :D goodbye` from:

```
asdasd dwref ADSADSADA Hello i'm Gabi :D goodbye asd asl sodjasdji asdoija
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you want to implement NLP, and are not familiar with regex a simple way to do it will be as follows:

```
import sys
s = "asdasd dwref ADSADSADA Hello i'm Gabi :D goodbye asd asl sodjasdji asdoija"
hello = s.find("Hello")
goodbye = s.find("goodbye")
if hello == -1 or goodbye == -1:
    print("Not found")
    sys.exit(0)
goodbye += len("goodbye") 
print(s[hello:goodbye])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a very basic regex:

(A demo and explanation on how it works: https://regex101.com/r/bO0rL7/2)

```
import re

string = "asdasd dwref ADSADSADA Hello i'm Gabi :D goodbye asd asl sodjasdji asdoija"


match = re.findall(r'hello .+ goodbye', string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
if match:
    print(match[0])
>> "Hello i'm Gabi :D goodbye"
```

Comment: really? is this works?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes. I've updated my answer, but it worked as well.

Comment: at first, I saw 2 goodbye's in ur regex string..